# How to parse field name using Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, parsing

My controller code:

```
     public function usersGroups(Request $request)
   {
    $resultArray = [];

        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name')->get();
        $resultArray['users'] = $users;

        $groups = DB::table('group')
            ->select('group.id','group.name')->get();
        $resultArray['groups'] = $groups;


    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

My response:

```
                     {
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Admin"
    }
],
"groups": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Our Lira"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "CM"
    }
  ]
     }
```

I have a field name "first_name" and I want to change it to "name" without changing the field name in the table. Just for this API I want to change first_name to name. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make an alias using MySQL:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name as name')->get();
```

Notice the `as name` in the select query.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

These are classes that let you transform your models to whatever JSON format/layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

i am not so good in api but you can achive it through setting alaias name

```
public function usersGroups(Request $request)
   {
    $resultArray = [];

        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->select('users.id','user_basic_info.first_name as name')->get();
        $resultArray['users'] = $users;

        $groups = DB::table('group')
            ->select('group.id','group.name')->get();
        $resultArray['groups'] = $groups;


    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

Can You try this if there is any error kindly comment below

Comment: You should get better in reading other people answers before you post your own :) as it is nothing different then what've answered 15 minutes before you did :)

Comment: sorry @nakov i have't refreshed the tab